# Use DateTime::modify() to change time of day

Tags: php, datetime

I want to change the time of day in a PHP `DateTime` object like this:

```
$date = new DateTime('2015-07-20 0:00');
var_dump($date->format(DateTime::ISO8601));

$date->modify('18:30:00');
var_dump($date->format(DateTime::ISO8601));
```

#### Expected output

```
string(24) "2015-07-20T00:00:00+0200"
string(24) "2015-07-20T18:30:00+0200"
```

#### Actual output

```
string(24) "2015-07-20T00:00:00+0200"
string(24) "2015-07-20T00:00:00+0200"
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the code works as expected in current PHP versions. You seem to run a very outdated (and unsecure) version <= 5.3.5. Please update!

[Tested with 3v4l.org:](http://3v4l.org/RFrgV)

#### Output for 5.3.6 - 7.0.0beta1, hhvm-3.6.1 - 3.8.0

```
string(24) "2015-07-20T00:00:00+0200"
string(24) "2015-07-20T18:30:00+0200"
```

#### Output for 5.2.0 - 5.3.5, hhvm-3.3.1

```
string(24) "2015-07-20T00:00:00+0200"
string(24) "2015-07-20T00:00:00+0200"
```

The [release notes for PHP 5.3.6](http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.3.6) mention several fixes in the `DateTime` extension. This one seems to target the described bug:

> - Fixed a bug in DateTime->modify() where absolute date/time statements had no effect. (Derick)